# RSA and xml-formatted public key in cocoa

Tags: xml, cocoa, rsa

How can I fill RSA structure with xml-formatted public key 
for using with  RSA functions on Mac OS X.
In other words:
There are following windows c# statements:

```
 RSACryptoServiceProvider rSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
 rSA.FromXmlString(xmlKey);
 return rSA.VerifyData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message), "MD5", signature);
```

how can I convert it to use with cocoa frameworks.

Thanks,
Vlad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to the problem.
First I convert XML-formatted RSA key to pem-format.
Second I use SSCrypto framework to verify data.